# Force new articles to have tags (term + subterm) associated with it

Tags: 7, nodes, taxonomy-terms, entities

[previous question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/13503/how-would-i-accomplish-the-following-drupal-site/13538#13538)

I have a site where articles need to be classified as, apple, banana, cranberry, etc....

Each category has sub-cats like apple - 1, apple - 2, ... banana - 1, banana - 2 ...

Now apples can have 10 subs and banana can have 200 or something like that.

I already make a vocabulary using taxonomy of all the terms and subterms.

What I need to do is have it so that users submit articles and it must have a category and sub-cat associated with it.

I want to do it this way so that I can have an index page of all apple articles, or just apple - 1, or banana - 2's ... etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re: Correct Tags comment:
I am not certain I understand what your concern is. :)

Two possible considerations:
1.  You can make the selection of the field mandatory when the content is submitted.
2.  You can expose the field in the view display to allow the user to make a selection

Comment: good enough thanks. I got hierarchical select plugin.

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeking to do is very basic and one of the early things you learn how to do in Drupal.  The simplest way to answer your question is to recommend you get a book such as Drupal 7 by Tom Geller or any of the other introductory Drupal books. Lynda.com also has a video series that can fill you in on how to use Drupal.  You can accomplish want you seek by modifying or creating a content type and adding field s linked to taxonomy terms. You can make it a requirement to add a value for each new entry.  Eventually you will want to master the Views module to find your content and display it.

Before you start working on the design of a site, yuo may want to spend some time studing Drupal basics. Drupal has a steep learning curve in the beginning and you will have to cover a lot of ground before it starts clicking and you will feel confident diving into a project.

Comment: I have 6 thousand terms or so. That would be a lot of checkboxes, I need something that repopulates the sub-categories after selecting the main category.

Comment: No checkboxes needed.  See my next response.

Answer (score 0):

RE: No checkboxes
The views module can filter your content based upon the URl using contextual filters to sort through the hierarchy and control what is displayed at each level.  Views can take the input from the URL (or panel module arguments) to determine what to display.

Path auto module would create the proper path aliases for each content entry.

I am currently working on a similar navigation problem and attempting to access the content through a menu generated using Taxonomy Menu  that has arranged all the terms in a hierarchical menu. (There is a bug in the design I have not yet solved, so I cannot guarantee it works from personal experience...yet.)

Comment: I first need it for authors to be able to select the correct tags first. Views can't really help with that

Comment: See my comment Re: Correct Tags.